# How to draw barplot in this way with Coreplot

Tags: core-plot

My image is cannot post so  the link is my picture

[image: http://m1.img.libdd.com/farm4/2013/0528/10/959DCB60497E3C74E998958C2F4674DB2E9198943E62C_1280_487.jpg]

I want to draw a chart like the image in iOS app

I use the CorePlot to help me to make this

My Question:

1. How to draw 3 barPlot whit  3 kinds color
2. How to draw a barPlot from the CPTXYAxis  0  to   -4000  in the Upside down way

Any help would be appreciate

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

A Core Plot graph can have as many plots as you need. They can be the same type or a mixture of different types. Use the `identifier` property to uniquely identify each plot and check it in the datasource to determine which plot is asking for data. Several Core Plot example apps have multiple plots in a graph; the *Plot Gallery* is a good place to start.

The "Plot Space Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* also shows how to "reverse" an axis. Just give it a negative length.